# POCO model class used in Entity Framework and ASP.NET MVC StackOverflow exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, devexpress, stack-overflow

This is driving me crazy!

I have created a code first ASP.NET MVC project and choose the Entity Framework Code First approach with migrations.

At the moment I have a problem which bubbles up from time to time, but in the current case I have a View which loads another PartialView. I actually try to create an AJAX Form as described in this DevExpress [link](http://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxDataEditorsDemos/Common/AjaxForm).

```
@using System.Drawing
@using ExtremeProduction.Internationalization
@model ExtremeProduction.Models.MyModel

@{
    Html.EnableClientValidation();
    ViewBag.Title = @Resources.MyModel;
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/RootMenuLayout.cshtml";
}

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/EditForm.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyModelAjaxForm", "MyModel",
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnBegin = "function(){ loadingPanel.Show(); }",
        OnComplete = "function(){ loadingPanel.Hide(); }",
        UpdateTargetId = "content",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
    },
    new
    {
        id = "validationForm",
        @class = "edit_form",
        style = "height: 200px; width: 600px;"
    }))
{
    <div id="content">
        @Html.Partial("MyModelFormPartial", Model)
    </div>
}

@Html.DevExpress().LoadingPanel(
    settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "loadingPanel";
        settings.Modal = true;
        settings.ContainerElementID = "validationForm";
        settings.Styles.LoadingDiv.BackColor = Color.White;
    }).GetHtml()
```

The MyModelFormPartial

```
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls
@using ExtremeProduction.Views.MyModelHelpers
@model ExtremeProduction.Models.MyModel

<div class="line">
    @Html.DevExpress().LabelFor(model => model.Property1, HtmlControlSettingsHelper.LabelSettingsMethod).GetHtml()
    @Html.DevExpress().TextBoxFor(model => model.Property1, HtmlControlSettingsHelper.TextBoxSettingsMethod).GetHtml()
</div>
<div class="line">
    @Html.DevExpress().LabelFor(model => model.PropertyDate, HtmlControlSettingsHelper.LabelSettingsMethod).GetHtml()
    @Html.DevExpress().DateEditFor(model => model.PropertyDate, HtmlControlSettingsHelper.DateEditSettingsMethod).GetHtml()
</div>
<div class="line">
    @Html.DevExpress().Label(HtmlControlSettingsHelper.LabelSettingsMethod).GetHtml()
    @Html.DevExpress().Button(
        settings =>
        {
            settings.Name = "btnUpdate";
            settings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "button";
            settings.Width = Unit.Pixel(180);
            settings.Text = "Process";
            settings.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
        }).GetHtml()
</div>
```

Heres my action in the controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MyModelAjaxForm(int? parentId)
        {
            MyModel myModel = new MyModel();
            if (parentId.HasValue) myModel = await Worker.GetMyModelWithParentReferenceId(parentId.Value);

            return View(myModel);
        }
```

MyModel has many related Navigation properties and couple of one to one Navigation Properties. Also I have some validation attributes. All the Code First configuration is added to EntityTypeConfiguration classes and then in the DbContext class.

```
public class MyModel : IObjectWithState
    {
        public MyModel()
        {
            _arxeia = new List<Arxeio>();
            _xromata = new List<XromaMyModel>();
            _fits = new List<Fit>();
            _ylika = new List<Yliko>();
            _plektiria = new List<Plektirio>();
            _ergastiriaka = new List<Ergastiriaka>();
            _tipomata = new List<Tipoma>();
            _vafes = new List<Vafi>();
            _qutexs = new List<Qutex>();
            _egriseis = new List<Egrisi>();
            _kopes = new List<Kopi>();
            _rafes = new List<Rafi>();
            _paragelia = new Paragelia();
            _parent = new Parent();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources),
              ErrorMessageResourceName = "MyModelKodikosRequired")]
        [Display(Name = "MyModelKodikos", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
        public string Property1 { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources),
            ErrorMessageResourceName = "MyModelImerominiaEnarxisRequired")]
        [Display(Name = "PropertyDate", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime PropertyDate { get; set; }

        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

        private Parent _parent;
        public virtual Parent Parent
        {
            get { return _parent; }
            set { _parent = value; }
        }

        private Paragelia _paragelia;
        public virtual Paragelia Paragelia
        {
            get { return _paragelia; }
            set { _paragelia = value; }
        }

        private ICollection<Arxeio> _arxeia;
        public virtual ICollection<Arxeio> Arxeia
        {
            get { return _arxeia; }
            set { _arxeia = value; }
        }

        private ICollection<XromaMyModel> _xromata;
        public virtual ICollection<XromaMyModel> Xromata
        {
            get { return _xromata; }
            set { _xromata = value; }
        }

        private ICollection<Fit> _fits;
        public virtual ICollection<Fit> Fits
        {
            get { return _fits; }
            set { _fits = value; }
        }

        private ICollection<Yliko> _ylika;
        public virtual ICollection<Yliko> Ylika
        {
            get { return _ylika; }
            set { _ylika = value; }
        }

        private ICollection<Tipoma> _tipomata;
        public virtual ICollection<Tipoma> Tipomata
        {
            get { return _tipomata; }
            set { _tipomata = value; }
        }

        private ICollection<Plektirio> _plektiria;
        public virtual ICollection<Plektirio> Plektiria
        {
            get { return _plektiria; }
            set { _plektiria = value; }
        }

        private ICollection<Ergastiriaka> _ergastiriaka;
        public virtual ICollection<Ergastiriaka> Ergastiriaka
        {
            get { return _ergastiriaka; }
            set { _ergastiriaka = value; }
        }

        private ICollection<Vafi> _vafes;
        public virtual ICollection<Vafi> Vafes
        {
            get { return _vafes; }
            set { _vafes = value; }
        }

        private ICollection<Qutex> _qutexs;
        public virtual ICollection<Qutex> Qutexs
        {
            get { return _qutexs; }
            set { _qutexs = value; }
        }

        private ICollection<Egrisi> _egriseis;
        public virtual ICollection<Egrisi> Egriseis
        {
            get { return _egriseis; }
            set { _egriseis = value; }
        }

        private ICollection<Kopi> _kopes;
        public virtual ICollection<Kopi> Kopes
        {
            get { return _kopes; }
            set { _kopes = value; }
        }

        private ICollection<Rafi> _rafes;
        public virtual ICollection<Rafi> Rafes
        {
            get { return _rafes; }
            set { _rafes = value; }
        }

        public State State { get; set; }
    }
```

**[EDIT]**
The EntityTypeConfiguration class.

```
internal class MyModelEntityTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyModel>
    {
        public MyModelEntityTypeConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("MyModels");
            HasKey(p => p.Id);
            Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            Property(p => p.RowVersion).IsRowVersion();
            Property(p => p.Property1).HasMaxLength(30);
            Ignore(p => p.State);
            HasMany(p => p.Xromata).WithRequired(p => p.MyModel).HasForeignKey(p => p.MyModelId);
            HasMany(p => p.Arxeia).WithRequired(p => p.MyModel).HasForeignKey(p => p.MyModelId);
            HasMany(p => p.Egriseis).WithRequired(p => p.MyModel).HasForeignKey(p => p.MyModelId);
            HasMany(p => p.Ergastiriaka).WithRequired(p => p.MyModel).HasForeignKey(p => p.MyModelId);
            HasMany(p => p.Fits).WithRequired(p => p.MyModel).HasForeignKey(p => p.MyModelId);
            HasMany(p => p.Kopes).WithRequired(p => p.MyModel).HasForeignKey(p => p.MyModelId);
            HasMany(p => p.Plektiria).WithRequired(p => p.MyModel).HasForeignKey(p => p.MyModelId);
            HasMany(p => p.Qutexs).WithRequired(p => p.MyModel).HasForeignKey(p => p.MyModelId);
            HasMany(p => p.Rafes).WithRequired(p => p.MyModel).HasForeignKey(p => p.MyModelId);
            HasMany(p => p.Tipomata).WithRequired(p => p.MyModel).HasForeignKey(p => p.MyModelId);
            HasMany(p => p.Vafes).WithRequired(p => p.MyModel).HasForeignKey(p => p.MyModelId);
            HasMany(p => p.Ylika).WithRequired(p => p.MyModel).HasForeignKey(p => p.MyModelId);
            HasOptional(p => p.Paragelia).WithRequired(p => p.MyModel);
            HasRequired(p => p.Parent).WithOptional(p => p.MyModel);
        }
    }
```

StackOverflow exception thrown and when debugging points to the constructor initializing the navigation properties.

The exception occurs when I just create a new instance of MyModel.

What do you think? Any additions, corrections, ideas on where to look about?

Comment: do you have a self referencing FK?

Comment: No, edited the question with adding the EntityTypeConfiguration class.

Comment: Actually, removing the constructor it just works OK as it seems!!! Any thoughts why? It has problem with instantiating all the navigation properties in the constructor.

Comment: well, how can `p => p.id` have a value in the constructor?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. I removed the MyModel constructor where I instantiate the Colections and Object properties, Navigation Properties. What do you mean? I haven't interacting with the Id property.

Comment: What is the exception callstack? The callstack usually clearly explains such kind of exceptions. If this is the infinity loop, the relevant fragment is the top part of the callstack, demonstrating the method from which the loop starts and one cycle of the loop.